# Using imacro to select span class and then clicking on button class

Tags: imacros

I want to click on a button class named wp06b

Normally I would do something like

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=CLASS:wpO6b
```

However it does not work in my case probably because there is many wp06b class [see printscreen below].

[image]

But there is only 1 span class named fr66p and inside it there there is only 1 button class wp06b.

So my question is how to use imacro to go inside fr66p and then click on button class  wp06b ?

I can select the class fr66n but then I do not know how to use imacro to select button class wp06b...

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:fr66n
wait seconds=2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum..., I normally don't answer when FCI is not mentioned... You may want to check my Profile for how to ask Qt's about iMacros "correctly"...

But yep, typical Application for "Double Relative Positioning"... (100+ Examples on the iMacros Forum):

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:fr66n
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=* ATTR=*
TAG POS=R-1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=CLASS:wpO6b
```

If the 'SPAN' Element is clickable, you'll need to add a "fake" 'EXTRACT', same for the 'R1' which will be the "_15y01" 'SPAN'...

[R-1 + R1] would also probably work, but not on "TYPE=*" which would catch the 'SECTION' Container, you would need to specify "TYPE=SPAN", I think..., but [R1 + R-1] seems to be easier and "safer" in this Case... URL not posted, I cannot test...

And if any of the 2 'DIV' + 'SVG' Elements inside the 'SPAN' and also inside the 'BUTTON' are unique or easily taggable, then you could use either one as 'Anchor' and you would only need "Single" 'Relative Positioning' with 'R-1'.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. (Was my first iMacro post I did not know about the way to ask properly. Will take into account if I have other iMacro post to open.)

Comment: Alright good, and Thanks also for accepting the Answer and the '+1', you got me pass the 500Pt Rep-Threshold, ah-ah...! - And tja, I'm more or less the only one answering Qt's about iMacros (correct Spelling btw), so I make my "own" Rules, ah-ah...!, ... which are the Rules of the iMacros Forum where I'm usually much more "Helpful" than on this Forum... (Mod there...). - But hum, OK, you're a "nice User", ah-ah...!

Comment: Hi chivracq I'm happy to hear that you are the expert (or guru as some may say) of iMacro in stackoverflow. I've learnt a lot about relatives positioning (liked that solution of going +1 and going back to the right element with the r-1 trick. That is wonderful. Have an excellent day :)

Comment: Yeah well, already 7 years active on the iMacros Forum (and Mod there since 2015 (I'm the only Mod on the whole Forum)) but I still call myself just an "Advanced" User, I never use "Guru"/"Expert" or whatever, only "Specialist" maybe sometimes...